# How to add unrelated directories to svn repository?

Tags: svn, directory, subclipse

I currently have an SVN repository that is based on the DEPLOYED location of:

/var/www

That means the root of the repository is a copy of everything needed below that.

My working copy is somewhere in my mess of a hard drive :-)

Now, I have other things that I want to add to it, based on the deployed location. Not sure where it is, (not my code base), but it's a JAVA deployment on the server. I know for a fact it's not off the same location on the server we're making.

So, how do I add this other directory to the repository to be versioned and keep track of where it goes in the deployment?

For example's sake, let's say everything below /usr/local/tomcat6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this sounds like a use case for [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html):

> keep track of where [the other directory] goes in the deployment

So, add the `/usr/local/tomcat6` directory as an `external` to your working copy and you should be fine.

Or did I get you wrong and `/usr/local/tomcat6` isn't versioned at all? In that case, you will have to create a repository for `/usr/local/tomcat6` before you can track any changes there (and add it as `external`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am thinking that some variant of what you propose will work. Yes, it's not versioned at all. I was hoping to put it into the same repository. It's on the development server at this time. I'll discuss your answer with my partner as soon as he gets back from vacation, at the end of this week.